# Meteor.js on heroku in Chrome, connection dies after refresh

Tags: javascript, heroku, meteor, meteorite

**EDIT 2:**

Oh, it acutally seems to work now. Hmm! Tried it on two different computers and got the same bug. Oh well! Thanks for taking time to comment.

**Original post:**

So I got this really simple meteor.js app deployed to both meteor.com and to heroku.

http://chrome-bug-test.meteor.com/
http://chrome-bug-test.herokuapp.com/

All the app does is display the Meteor.status() object.

The meteor.com-hosted one works just fine in all browsers, connects quite quickly. But in Chrome, when I go to the [Heroku-hosted](http://chrome-bug-test.herokuapp.com/) one, it works at first, but if I refresh the browser window it gets stuck in a waiting/retry limbo that never gets connected. If I open a new tab in Chrome and go to the [Heroku-hosted](http://chrome-bug-test.herokuapp.com/) one it connects just fine again until I refresh the tab. Again: waiting-limbo. Annoying!

It works just fine in all other browsers I try in (Mac only).

Anyone knows what's up with this Chrome/Heroku/Meteor-thing?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Oh, and here's all the app-code: http://pastebin.com/9YDFmXc7

Comment: Did you use the heroku buildpack for meteor?

Comment: The meteorite-one acutally: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

Comment: I'm actually seeing the same error on my distribution here: https://talkalytics.herokuapp.com/ - the websockets are failing as well. Very odd

Comment: Where did you see Heroku support websockets ? AFAIK they don't

Comment: They don't. However I have the exact same problem with the meteor version without websockets, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Hi there, I tried two urls posted by you, and both of them showed same behavior. They both worked and I was not able to re-produce the error that you mentioned.

Comment: Hi @user482594 and thanks. Did you use Chrome on Mac and refreshed the page?

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows. It looks good to me when I checked it again today. I am not sure how mature Chrone on Mac is.

Comment: Pretty sure it's as mature as the Windows version. :) Good to know that it's only the Mac version that's affected though, thanks!